# A forum solution with an Q&A option and API

Tags: php, forum

I have a project that needs to have a forum integrated. I could implement it myself for the most custom experience, but I'm also looking at existing solutions.

- My biggest concern is that I'd prefer a solution that provides an API so that tasks like user creation, login, etc. can be automated through the API.
- It would ideally also be able to act both as a traditional forum and as a Q&A type forum almost like the style we have here.

There's phpBB, vBulletin but they're older so I doubt they meet the above 2 criteria. I also found Vanilla which is new but looks ok. I installed it very quickly on my localhost and it's all about plugins and I'm not sure how much real community support it has. Does anyone have experience with it? or knows if it can meet the 2 criteria I mentioned?

I'm interested in getting some suggestions from others who've implemented something similar recently.

Comment: already thought about using drupal and check for a forum plugin?

Comment: @ITroubs, Yeah, thought about it. Drupal has a QA distro, the one by the Lullabot guy, forgot his name, but it's really really primitive and not ready for prime time yet. I'd prefer a strictly forum software for this if something exists that meets my criteria. But if you already know a couple of Drupal plugins that can do this, by all means, I will consider them.